How to plot this data set, ignoring the initial oscillation?
Suppose I have an array given as:
 data={0.7836, 0.7836, 2.2782, 2.2783, 3.6371, 3.6431, 4.7382,4.8641, 5.5609, 6.0654, 6.7291, 7.433, 8.1913, 8.9940, 9.8377, 10.7193, 11.6362, 12.5865, 13.5683, 14.5802, 15.6208, 16.6889, 17.7834, 18.9034, 20.048}

I need to plot the successive difference between the data points. For this, I used the following code:
ListLinePlot[Differences[data]]

that results

The problem with this plot is it is oscillatory at the beginning which is correct as first a few pairs of data points are close/same.
However, I need to highlight the overall decreasing pattern along with this oscillation. I mean to say how to get the graph to be like this

I tried to Drop the repeated data points and used Show to see both graphs, but it did not work. It was because one of the data sets had more data points than the others so the other one shifted to the left.
ListLinePlot[{Differences[data], Differences[Drop[data, {2, 8, 2}]]}]


How to make it look like the above?

What you are looking for is to find the data envelope.
One possible way
data = {0.7836, 0.7836, 2.2782, 2.2783, 3.6371, 3.6431, 4.7382, 
   4.8641, 5.5609, 6.0654, 6.7291, 7.433, 8.1913, 8.9940, 9.8377, 
   10.7193, 11.6362, 12.5865, 13.5683, 14.5802, 15.6208, 16.6889, 
   17.7834, 18.9034, 20.048};
data2 = Differences[data];
d = FindPeaks[data2, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
ListLinePlot[{data2, d}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]


But there are many more methods that should produce better results. Such as EstimatedBackground and QuantileRegression and others. I have not used these much so no time now to look into them for you input.
Here are links for you to look at:
upper-envelope-of-data
envelope-estimation
envelope-for-harmonic-oscillator
plotting-a-trig-functions-along-with-its-envelope

We may change the duplicated points by the mean of their neighbors. This gets complicated because the duplicated points are not exactly equal. Therefore, we must first determine the positions of the points to be changed before taking the mean. We request that points are duplicates if the dot differ by less than 0.2:
data = {0.7836, 0.7836, 2.2782, 2.2783, 3.6371, 3.6431, 4.7382, 
   4.8641, 5.5609, 6.0654, 6.7291, 7.433, 8.1913, 8.9940, 9.8377, 
   10.7193, 11.6362, 12.5865, 13.5683, 14.5802, 15.6208, 16.6889, 
   17.7834, 18.9034, 20.048};
pos = 1 + Position[Rest[data] - Most[data], x_ /; Abs[x] < 0.2] // 
  Flatten

Now we can change the duplicate points:
(data[[#]] = (data[[# - 1]] + data[[# + 1]])/2) & /@ pos
ListPlot[data]


With the problematic points eliminated, we can now take the differences:
ListLinePlot[Differences[data]]



I'd suggest using an Interpolation instead of computing finite differences.
First, augment your data list with corresponding abscissa values:
data = {0.7836, 0.7836, 2.2782, 2.2783, 3.6371, 3.6431, 4.7382, 4.8641, 5.5609,
        6.0654, 6.7291, 7.433, 8.1913, 8.9940, 9.8377, 10.7193, 11.6362, 12.5865,
        13.5683, 14.5802, 15.6208, 16.6889, 17.7834, 18.9034, 20.048};

dd = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, data]
(*    {{1, 0.7836}, {2, 0.7836}, {3, 2.2782}, {4, 2.2783}, {5, 3.6371},
       {6, 3.6431}, {7, 4.7382}, {8, 4.8641}, {9, 5.5609}, {10, 6.0654},
       {11, 6.7291}, {12, 7.433}, {13, 8.1913}, {14, 8.994}, {15, 9.8377},
       {16, 10.7193}, {17, 11.6362}, {18, 12.5865}, {19, 13.5683}, {20, 14.5802},
       {21, 15.6208}, {22, 16.6889}, {23, 17.7834}, {24, 18.9034}, {25, 20.048}}    *)

Now extract two sub-sets (even and odd abscissa values) and interpolate them:
i1 = Interpolation[dd[[1 ;; ;; 2]]];
i2 = Interpolation[dd[[2 ;; ;; 2]]];

Note that Interpolation has lots of options, for example InterpolationOrder.
Show the first derivatives of these interpolations:
pl1 = Plot[i1'[n], Flatten[{n, i1["Domain"]}], PlotStyle -> Blue];
pl2 = Plot[i2'[n], Flatten[{n, i2["Domain"]}], PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[pl1, pl2]



Your workaround is great, and I appreciate the clever trick. I hope it comes in handy for addressing another challenge. However, it is not the answer I require.

It was certainly a wild guess on my side. Cheers!
